# How to configure hibernate for a on-premise HANA DB via cloud connector which is exposed over TCP?

Tags: java, hibernate, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up a Spring project on SAP Cloud Neo Environment, there is an on-premise HANA DB which is exposed over TCP. I am using SOCK proxy to connect to DB, but when I deploy my application with hibernate configuration, all the services start giving 500 error code.
I checked raw JDBC connection with SOCK PROXY setup which is working fine but fails with Hibernate configuration

I checked raw JDBC connection with SOCK PROXY setup which is working fine but fails with Hibernate configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can implement a CustomDataSource class which extends AbstractDriverBasedDataSource, after the connection is done in proxy we have to manually close the connection.